# SwiftUI Charts extension Image: Plottable

Tags: swiftui, charts, plottable

Is there any sensible way to create sth like `extension Image: Plottable` and pass to .value inside BarMark. Or there is any other possibility to have images below charts instead text?

I try sth like but it of course doesn't work

```
extension Image: Plottable {
    
    public var primitivePlottable: String {
        ????
    }
    
    public init?(primitivePlottable: String) {
        self.init(primitivePlottable)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok i found a slightly different solution to this problem using annotation modifier with position: .bottom like:

```
BarMark(x: .value("Shape Type", shape.type),
                        y:  .value("Total Count", shape.count))
                .annotation(position: .bottom, alignment: .center, spacing: 10, content: {
                    Image(shape.type)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                })
```